# How to write a powershell script in order to convert 400+ virtual machines into managed disks

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

How can I write a powershell to convert virtual machines from unmamnaged disks to managed disks? Is it possible?

Comment: Follow the steps in [Convert Azure VM from Unmanaged disk to Managed disk](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/virtual-machines/windows/convert-unmanaged-to-managed-disks.md).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Azure Powershell Module: [Introducing the new Azure PowerShell Az module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-2.2.0).

you can list all the VMs in a subscription using this [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azresource?view=azps-2.2.0)

```
$vms = Get-AzResource -ResourceType Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines
```

Then you can loop through the $vms and and convert a virtual machine with blob-based disks to a virtual machine with managed disks using this [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/ConvertTo-AzVMManagedDisk?view=azps-2.2.0):

```
foreach($vm in$vms){
    ConvertTo-AzVMManagedDisk `
        -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName `
        -VMName $vm.Name
}
```

Comment: how to covert 400+ virtual machines in separate RGs back to back?

Comment: Just a get a list of your vms and loop through the list